# My javascript to removeClass + addClass when click only work on Chrome but not Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, my piece of javascript to remove/add class when clicking on a link only works on Google Chrome. On Firefox, it executes once, then doesn't repeat. On IE, it just straight out doestn't work at all. (latest version of Firefox and Chrome, IE 11)

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be much appreciated!

Simple JSFiddle of the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/UDxtM/

This is the javascript:

```
$('[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function() {
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('animated flipInY');
    $('.tab-pane').addClass('animated flipInY');
});
```

Some dummy content:

```
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#front" data-toggle="tab">Front</a></li>
    <li><a href="#back" data-toggle="tab">Back</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="front">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="back">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit #1:** 
The CSS transition is from animate.css http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. It works flawlessly on modern web browsers if I just use them without the piece of javascript there.  I don't think the CSS is the problem.

**Edit #2:**
Apparently it works on others' IE10 and IE11 but just not mine. That still leaves the problem with Firefox only play the code once.

Comment: Works here in IE 10, and better than in Chrome. But in FF it only works once as you noted.

Comment: My finger would be pointing at the CSS transitions you're using, not jQuery. Have you checked the support for them in the versions of FF and IE?

Comment: The CSS transition is from animate.css [link](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). It's fairly well-known and work flawless on modern browsers.  I'll add a note to this in my original post.

Comment: Works great form me in IE 11, Firefox is as you reported.

Comment: Eh, I need to check my IE 11 then, haha. I wonder why it isn't working on my IE 11; everything's at default settings, no plugin or addon except flash.  Thanks for the reports!

Comment: @user3753984 Do you have an HTML5 doctype? Data types are and HTML5 element. Google Chrome might just be recognizing it because it is smart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing the classes and adding them again immediately after – so if for performance optimization reasons the browser decides not to do a re-paint in between those two actions, there will be no visible effect at all.

By using a small timeout to “de-couple” adding the classes again, it seems to work in FF as well:

```
$('[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function () {
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('animated flipInY');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.tab-pane').addClass('animated flipInY');
    },
    10);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UDxtM/3/

Comment: Just what I came up with ---- +1. Good job!!

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  Now I just need to figure out why it doesn't work on my IE only (works on everyone else posted here but just not me alone).  I wonder whether there's a difference between IE11 for WIndows 8.1 vs IE11 for Windows 7.