# Style change postponed due to sync calls

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to build a loading bar for a set of ajax calls. Right now im doing it synchronously, and the issue is that style changes only take place after the set of sync calls are finished.

This fiddle illustrates my problem. https://jsfiddle.net/cbwevtda/

```
$("button").on('click',function(d) {
    document.getElementById("myH2").style.color = "#ff0000";
    document.getElementById("myP").style.color = "magenta";
    sleep(3000);
    document.getElementById("myP2").style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color = "lightblue";
})
```

All the colors are only changed after the sleep function is finished. Is there a way to synchronously apply changes to style?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My javascript to removeClass + addClass when click only work on Chrome but not Firefox or IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294121/my-javascript-to-removeclass-addclass-when-click-only-work-on-chrome-but-not-f)

Comment: You need to “interrupt” the JS execution, by a small timeout or requestanimationframe - see duplicate for a simple example, that’s basically the same issue over there.

Comment: yes, id like to change the width of the bar when a request is complete.

Comment: Why `document.getElementById("myP2").style.color = "blue"` instead of `$('#myP2').css('color','blue')` ?

Comment: Your suggestion is jquery and the other is pure js. I dont think its relevant

Comment: _“but not sure why as the reasoning isnt quite the same”_ - yes, that is the same issue. Your `sleep` function doesn’t cause any interruption in the JS execution, this is all one “operation”. The JS engine does not hand control back over to the rendering engine, before it is done.

Comment: I see. So it seems that js will try to render style changes in batches rather than one by one. Is there a more elegant way of making such interruptions?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running synchronously. Each line is executed one after the other and must wait for the previous line to complete. The main thread waits for the 'sleep' function to return before carrying on to the next line in the code.

With JavaScript you should try to write asynchronous code as much as possible so that the main thread is not blocked

You can see the difference by changing your example to this...

```
$("button").on('click',function(d) {
    document.getElementById("myH2").style.color = "#ff0000";
    document.getElementById("myP").style.color = "magenta";

    setTimeout(function() {
        sleep(3000);
    }, 10);

    document.getElementById("myP2").style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color = "lightblue";
})
```

This tells JavaScript to queue an anonymous callback function to be executed at the first possible instance after 10ms have elapsed.

When you're dealing with AJAX this won't be an issue as AJAX is inherently asynchronous and will not block the main thread.